# Calling setNeedsDisplay in layoutSubviews?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, drawrect, layoutsubviews

Consider a view with a custom background that is drawn in `drawRect:`. If the view changes size, the background need to be redrawn.

Is this a bad idea?

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If it is, what would be a better alternative considering I can't control who changes the size of the view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dont do that, it's not necessary. Set the `contentMode` of the view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`:

> UIViewContentModeRedraw
>
> Redisplays the view when the bounds change by invoking the setNeedsDisplay method.
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> Declared in UIView.h.

This will achieve the same effect.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new. Also, it appears to work! :)

Comment: Note that's it's also fine to send `setNeedsDisplay` in `layoutSubviews`, which you might want to do if you only need to redraw on some size changes.

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly to add a line of code to set `contentMode` is it in `init:` , `layoutSubviews()` or ? Because i have added it in `init:` but it dint work for me.

Comment: @SunilRao wherever you create the view should be fine