# Load data on fist tab view controller before it launch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, nsurl

I'm working on an app in Swift 2.2.

I created a tabbed application from the initial template. I then added some code to my FirstViewController class, in order to download, parse, and display some JSON-formatted data.

This is the contents of my FirstViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var siteNameLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var siteName = ""
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://wheretogo.com.mx/backends/service.php")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                //print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                    if let appInfo = json["appInfo"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        siteName = appInfo[0]["siteName"] as! String
                        self.siteNameLabel.text = siteName

                    }

                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                } 
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Fetching and parsing the data actually works. The problem is that the data is only displayed when I select the second tab and then go back to the first.

When it loads the label, it has the default text and it changes when I go to another tab and come back to the first, then the self.siteNameLabel.text = siteName.

I think an init can solve it, but I don't know how, or maybe a delay?

Or how can I handle the downloading data before my first view controller load.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: after download the data you should update the UIview

Comment: Are you sure you're using iOS 2.2? That was 8 years ago...

Comment: can you refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434794/calling-setneedsdisplay-in-layoutsubviews

Comment: sorry, my wrong I'm using Swift 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have something to do with the thread you use to update your UI. Note that the completion block utilised by `dataTaskWithRequest` is performed on a background thread.

Since Apple only allows UI updates to be done on the main thread, you can solve this issue by using a dispatch block like so (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20052746/699963)):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.siteNameLabel.text = siteName
})
```

Also, note that if you want the data that your UI depends on to update each time `FirstViewController` is shown, you should have your code in `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The dispatch_async solved my problem, it takes some milliseconds to load the data but it does.